# Reduce code duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, code-duplication

Currently I have quite many classes (5) that have just 2 properties but have different names for different purposes:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {

    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {

    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}


........

  public class Class5
 {
    public Class5()
    {

    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have for each of those classes a method that will return a `List<Class>`.

```
 public static List<Class1> GetClass1()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> s = GetSomeResults1();

        List<Class1> _s = new List<Class1>();

        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            c.Id = item.Key;
            c.Value = item.Value;

            _s.Add(c);
        }

        return _s;
    }


  public static List<Class2> GetClass2()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> s = GetSomeResults2();

        List<Class2> _s = new List<Class2>();

        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            Class2 c = new Class2();
            c.Id = item.Key;
            c.Value = item.Value;

            _s.Add(c);
        }

        return _s;
    }

  ......

   public static List<Class5> GetClass5()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> s = GetSomeResults5();

        List<Class5> _s = new List<Class5>();

        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            Class5 c = new Class5();
            c.Id = item.Key;
            c.Value = item.Value;

            _s.Add(c);
        }

        return _s;
    }
```

Any advise how can I better make this code?

Comment: Code models a domain. Perhaps it is not a question of how to improve the code but how model the domain better. So, we need to know what the application is to answer the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 'Code Review'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a base class to put the shared properties and functions in:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // shared properties and methods
}

public class Class1 :  BaseClass
{
    // own properties and methods
}

public class Class2 :  BaseClass
{
    // own properties and methods
}
```

Comment: And possibly make the `BaseClass` abstract

Comment: That would be an option indeed to prevent using it on itself, but not necessary as far as we can tell now.

Comment: I followed your example, except I just use the BaseClass. I removed all Class1-Class5 and made just one single class and based on Enum parameter I get the results as a Dictionary<string,string> and then make a List<BaseClass> and return it.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest create a seperate class for

```
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
```

and call inside class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class Class1 : BaseClass
{
    public Class1()
    {
    }
}

public class Class2: BaseClass
{
    public Class2()
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can make a generic method which returns the interface of `List<T>` where T is of type BaseClass

```
public static List<T> GetClass<T>(Func<Dictionary<string, string> func) where T : BaseClass, new()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> s = func();

    List<T> _s = new List<T>();

    foreach (var item in s)
    {
        T c = new T();
        c.Id = item.Key;
        c.Value = item.Value;

        _s.Add(c);
    }

    return _s;
}
```

Then call:

```
List<Class2> class2list = GetClass<Class2>(GetSomeResults2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class inheritance and put common parts of code to a base class like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base class
/// </summary>
public class BaseClass
{
  public BaseClass()
  {
  }

  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }

  public virtual List<BaseClass> GetClass();

  protected List<TClass> GetList<TClass> (Dictionary<string, string> s) where TClass : BaseClass, new() {
    List<TClass> _s = new List<TClass>();

    foreach (var item in s)
    {
        TClass c = new TClass();
        c.Id = item.Key;
        c.Value = item.Value;

        _s.Add(c);
    }

    return _s;
  }
}

public class Class1 : BaseClass
  {
    public override List<Class1> GetClass() {
       Dictionary<string, string> s = GetSomeResults1();
       return GetList<Class1>(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Hofman's answer is right, but i'd also add that using a `BaseClass` would allow you to reduce the amount of code working with your classes.

```
public static List<T> GetClassList() where T:BaseClass
{
    Dictionary<string, string> s = GetSomeResults<T>();

    List<T> _s = new List<T>();

    foreach (var item in s)
    {
        T c = new T();
        c.Id = item.Key;
        c.Value = item.Value;

        _s.Add(c);
    }

    return _s;
}
```

Changing just this function is not enough though, you also need a way to implement the `GetSomeResults()` methods. I don't really know what your logic looks like and how different these methods are, but smth like this can help in the worst case when methods are completely different.

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetSomeResults<T>() where T : BaseClass
{
    if (T == typeof(Class1))
    {
        return GetSomeResults1();
    }
    else if (T == typeof(Class2))
    {
    //You got it..
    }
}
```